# Tinymce does work, but *some* styles won't be saved to the database (?!)

Tags: database, format, tinymce

I'm trying to use tinymce. So far so good, so I tried to add some formats (like adding some background colour, or making some styles for headers.

It does show everything in place but it won't be saved to the database with the format.

This is my configuration:

```
  tinymce.init({
    entity_encoding : "raw",
    selector: '.wysiwyg',
    plugins: "image textcolor colorpicker hr link table lists advlist contextmenu",
    toolbar: 'styleselect | undo redo | bold italic underline | link image | forecolor backcolor | hr | table',
    menubar: "",
    contextmenu: "bold italic underline | bullist numlist | link | cell row column deletetable",
    content_css : "style-tinymce.css",
    valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]",
    image_caption: true,
    style_formats: [
      {title: 'Image Left', selector: 'img', styles: {
        'float' : 'left',
        'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
      }},
      {title: 'Image Right', selector: 'img', styles: {
        'float' : 'right',
        'margin': '0 10px 0 10px'
      }},
      { title: 'Encabezado', 
        block: 'h2', 
        styles: {   'color': '#0871ad' } 
        },
      { title: 'Texto Resaltado', 
        inline: 'span', 
        styles: {   'color': '#000000',
                    'background-color': '#f6f433' 
                } 
        }
    ]   
  });
```

These are the steps that I'm taking:
I do add the image:
[image]

I set the image with the format "float right":
[image]

I add some special format to the text:
[image]

This is what is saved into the database:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus accumsan, massa at sollicitudin vulputate, mauris sapien vestibulum libero, id mollis arcu neque vitae odio. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla ornare tristique tempor. In finibus volutpat sapien. Nulla mi justo, luctus ut volutpat a, tienim. Mauris molestie placerat dui sed consectetur.

I did cut the est of the Lorem Ipsum text. As you can see, the image is saved, but the format won't.

It does not happen the same with the bold, or italic, for example, they do get saved. It only happens with my special `style_formats`.

I'm using tinymce 4.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone some day: the problem was this ine:

```
valid_elements : "img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name]",
```

Telling tinymce that it should accept IMG as a valid element, I was actually telling them that it was the only valid element that it should accept!